# Why is my Java swing window not showing up?

Tags: java, linux, swing, netbeans

so I'm starting to learn Java Swing, following a YouTube video.. installed Java 8 and NetBeans 8.0 in Linux Ubuntu 14.04. Made a new Java application, and wrote the following code:

```
package basicswing;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class BasicSwing extends JFrame {

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    JButton b = new JButton("Hello");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BasicSwing();
    }

    public BasicSwing() {
        super("Basic Swing App");

        setSize(400,300);
        setResizable(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        p.add(b);
        add(p);

        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

When I clean, build, and then run the project, it shows that a Java project is running, but I don't see the Frame, it doesn't pop up.. I don't actually think it's a code issue, I've tried it with different code, and the frame still doesn't show. I can't figure out if it's a NetBeans issue or a Java issue.. or maybe something else?

Comment: When I run the code in my environment, I am able to see the frame. There is no error in your code.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just coming up behind other windows?

Comment: The code is running windows machine perfectally

Comment: Works in my eclipse juno too

Comment: Works for me, on Linux Mint.

Comment: 1) `setSize(400,300); .. setVisible(true);` should be `..pack(); setVisible(true);` 2) A GUI should be constructed on the EDT. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: Where's the main method? Who is constructing this class?

Comment: Tried a number of these solutions, nothing seems to work in Linux. However, I'm able to see the window in Windows.. so it may be some sort of Linux/Java/environment issue.. guess I'll use Windows for Swing.

Answer (score 3):

It is an environment (NetBeans maybe?) issue. Try running from command line:

```
$ javac BasicSwing.java
$ java BasicSwing
```

The code is correct and displays the frame.